# Keep a fixed header on the same level as another section

Tags: html, css

I have a header and a section in my CSS. The header is a 100% height vertical menu. I would like it to move with my contents and this works fine but when resizing the screen at a certain size my section with contents will go behind or in front of my header.

I would like to prevent the section with contents going behind or in front of the header when resizing. Any hints? So actually I would like the functionality like when you would have the header and contents section without the header being on position:fixed but then with my header fixed.

So currently I have something like

```
header{
width:300px;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
}

#contents{
width:850px; 
}
```

The contents should not 'overwrite' the fixed header when resizing and scrolling left/right.

JSFiddle URL: https://jsfiddle.net/elsticky/ahqohqpg/

Comment: Post your **enough CSS** and **HTML**, to get an answer. Also better if you could create a similar demo using **Snippet** or **[JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)**.

Comment: Maybe if you give the header a higher z-index (since as of your code, it's on the same level as the content now), it would help.

Comment: Here's my JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/elsticky/ahqohqpg/ . The 'text' should keep its position when scrolling to the right and not go behind the header.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a min-width for both the header and the content, this will result in a scrolled window, after decreasing your window size below that level.
Also set a container div and try setting its width.

Comment: I think you should post some code snippet for your answer.